# How to specify the underlying type of an enum in Rust?

Tags: enums, rust

Given a simple enum with a few un-typed values, it might be desirable that the size of this enum use a smaller integral type then the default. For example, this provides the ability to store the enum in an array of `u8`.

```
enum MyEnum { 
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
}
```

It's possible to use a `u8` array and compare them against some constants, but I would like to have the benefit of using enums to ensure all possibilities are handled in a match statement.

How can this be specified so its `size_of` matches the desired integer type?

Comment: Note, there are some similar questions already - but they are asking about interfacing other languages *(making my initial attempts to find this information fail!)* - so asked a new question.

Comment: While this is marked as a duplicate, the other question is about C++ FFI.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This can be done using the [representation (`repr`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html)  specifier.

```
#[repr(u8)]
enum MyEnum { A = 0, B, C, }
```

Assigned values outside the range of the type will raise a compiler warning.