# How can I map a Name to an Index in rust?

Tags: rust, indexing, enums

I'm working with a list of inputs for a small neural network. They're all f32, but they all represent something different (height, width, x, y , etc.).

In order to keep track of what information goes to what inputs, I *could* use a list of constants. E.G.

```
    const HEIGHT: usize = 0;
    const WIDTH: usize = 1;
    const X: usize = 2;
    const Y: usize = 3;
```

But I'm concerned about robustness. In the future, I might try to add another input that is *not* appended to the list, and forget to update all of the subsequent values. EG.

```
    const HEIGHT: usize = 0;
    const WIDTH: usize = 1;
    const DEPTH: usize = 2;
    const X: usize = 2;
    const Y: usize = 3;
```

A more ideal solution might be something like C enums, which correspond to 0..n. However, this doesn't make sense for Rust enums. I could probably make a macro that makes constants for a list of names, but is there a cleaner way to do this that's built in?

Comment: This kind of does make sense for Rust enums. You can use [`#[repr(usize)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#repru-repri)

Comment: Another option might be using a struct with `#[repr(C)]`. If all the fields are `f32`, then the struct is guarantted to have the same memory layout as an array.

Comment: @BallpointBen You don't need `#[repr(usize)]` if you don't plan to pass the transmute the enum to `usize`. You can use `as usize` to convert.

Comment: Rel: [Is there a way to index an array by enums in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900810/is-there-a-way-to-index-an-array-by-enums-in-rust)