# How to ensure every enum variant can be returned from a specific function at compile time?

Tags: enums, rust

I have an enum:

```rust
enum Operation {
    Add,
    Subtract,
}

impl Operation {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Result<Self, &str> {
        match s {
            "+" => Ok(Self::Add),
            "-" => Ok(Self::Subtract),
            _ => Err("Invalid operation"),
        }
    }
}
```

I want to ensure at compile time that every enum variant is handled in the `from` function.

Why do I need this? For example, I might add a `Product` operation and forget to handle this case in the `from` function:

```rust
enum Operation {
    // ...
    Product,
}

impl Operation {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Result<Self, &str> {
        // No changes, I forgot to add a match arm for `Product`.
        match s {
            "+" => Ok(Self::Add),
            "-" => Ok(Self::Subtract),
            _ => Err("Invalid operation"),
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to guarantee that match expression returns every variant of an enum? If not, what is the best way to mimic this behaviour?

Answer (score 16):

A solution would be to generate the whole enumeration, variants and translation arms with a macro:

```
macro_rules! operations {
    (
        $($name:ident: $chr:expr)*
    ) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        pub enum Operation {
            $($name,)*
        }
        impl Operation {
            fn from(s: &str) -> Result<Self, &str> {
                match s {
                    $($chr => Ok(Self::$name),)*
                    _ => Err("Invalid operation"),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

operations! {
    Add: "+"
    Subtract: "-"
}
```

This way adding a variant is trivial and you can't forget a parsing. It's also a very DRY solution.

It's easy to extend this construct with other functions (for example the inverse translation) that you'll surely need later and you won't have to duplicate the parsing char.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a35d55ccc0127db5eb1b0203c141c2b8)

Comment: I'll leave my answer, but this is definitely better!

Answer (score 10):

While there is certainly a complicated — and fragile — way to inspect your code with procedural macros, a much better path is to use tests. Tests are more robust, much faster to write, and will verify the circumstances in which each variant is returned, not just that it appears somewhere.

If you are concerned that the tests might continue to pass after you add new variants to the enum, you can use a macro to ensure that all cases are tested:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Operation {
    Add,
    Subtract,
}

impl Operation {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Result<Self, &str> {
        match s {
            "+" => Ok(Self::Add),
            "-" => Ok(Self::Subtract),
            _ => Err("Invalid operation"),
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! ensure_mapping {
    ($($str: literal => $variant: path),+ $(,)?) => {
        // assert that the given strings produce the expected variants
        $(assert_eq!(Operation::from($str), Ok($variant));)+

        // this generated fn will never be called but will produce a 
        // non-exhaustive pattern error if you've missed a variant
        fn check_all_covered(op: Operation) {
            match op {
                $($variant => {})+
            };
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn all_variants_are_returned_by_from() {
   ensure_mapping! {
      "+" => Operation::Add,
       "-" => Operation::Subtract,
   }
}
```