# How do I convert a C-style enum generated by bindgen to another enum?

Tags: enums, rust, rust-bindgen

I am creating bindings in Rust for a C library and Bindgen generated enums like:

```
// Rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub enum rmw_qos_history_policy_t {
    RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = 0,
    RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_LAST = 1,
    RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_ALL = 2,
    RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_UNKNOWN = 3,
}
```

I need to convert these to:

```
// Rust
pub enum QoSHistoryPolicy {
    SystemDefault = 0,
    KeepLast = 1,
    KeepAll = 2,
    Unknown = 3,
}
```

When importing constant values from this C library:

```c
// C library
const rmw_qos_history_policy_t some_value_from_C = RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_SYSTEM_DEFAULT;
```

I would like to do something like:

```
let some_value: QoSHistoryPolicy = some_value_from_C;
```

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler does not inspect enums for ABI compatibility, and as such does not provide a direct way to convert values between these types. A few possible solutions follow.

#### 1. One-by-one matching

This is trivial and safe, albeit leading to exhaustive code.

```rust
impl From<rmw_qos_history_policy_t> for QoSHistoryPolicy {
    fn from(x: rmw_qos_history_policy_t) -> Self {
        use rmw_qos_history_policy_t::*;
        match x {
            RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_SYSTEM_DEFAULT => QoSHistoryPolicy::SystemDefault,
            RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_LAST => QoSHistoryPolicy::KeepLast,
            RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_ALL => QoSHistoryPolicy::KeepAll,
            RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_UNKNOWN => QoSHistoryPolicy::Unknown,
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. Casting + FromPrimitive

Rust allows you to convert field-less enums into an integer type using the `as` operator. The opposite conversion is not always safe however. Derive `FromPrimitive` using the `num` crate to obtain the missing piece.

```rust
#[derive(FromPrimitive)]
pub enum QoSHistoryPolicy { ... }

impl From<rmw_qos_history_policy_t> for QoSHistoryPolicy {
    fn from(x: rmw_qos_history_policy_t) -> Self {
        FromPrimitive::from_u32(x as _).expect("1:1 enum variant matching, all good")
    }
}
```

#### 3. Need an enum?

In the event that you just want an abstraction to low-level bindings, you might go without a new enum type.

```
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct QoSHistoryPolicy(rmw_qos_history_policy_t);
```

The type above contains the same information and binary representation, but can expose an encapsulated API. The conversion from the low-level type to the high-level type becomes trivial. The main downside is that you lose pattern matching over its variants.

#### 4. You're on your own

When **absolutely sure** that the two enums are equivalent in their binary representation, you can `transmute` between them. The compiler won't help you here, this is far from recommended.

```
unsafe {
    let policy: QoSHistoryPolicy = std::mem::transmute(val);
}
```

**See also:**

- [How do I match enum values with an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028854/how-do-i-match-enum-values-with-an-integer)

Comment: Thank you ! Thinking about it, I _want_ that compilation fails if upstream API changes so I'm going with option 1 :) With the other solutions, not only there is a possibility of panic, but there is also a runtime check and hence penalty.

Comment: And, **option 1** is exhaustive but you can see the beautiful transformation of a long, long name into a neatly namespaced system of simple names :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks to be a good candidate for the `From` [trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) on `QoSHistoryPolicy`.

```rust
impl From<rmw_qos_history_policy_t> for QoSHistoryPolicy {
    fn from(raw: rmw_qos_history_policy_t) -> Self {
        match raw {
            rmw_qos_history_policy_t::RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_SYSTEM_DEFAULT => QoSHistoryPolicy::SystemDefault,
            rmw_qos_history_policy_t::RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_LAST => QoSHistoryPolicy::KeepLast,
            rmw_qos_history_policy_t::RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_ALL => QoSHistoryPolicy::KeepAll,
            rmw_qos_history_policy_t::RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_UNKNOWN => QoSHistoryPolicy::Unknown
        }
    }
}
```

so this should now work

```rust
let some_value: QoSHistoryPolicy = some_value_from_C.into();
```