# How do i Compare Enum Values while ignoring their Associated Values?

Tags: rust, enums

I'm trying to find a way to compare enums, the desired behavior would be the following code snippet printing "equal":

The comparison should ignore the associated value but only consider the enum value.

```rust
fn main() {
    let first = test::a(0);
    let second = test::a(1);
    if first == second {
        println!("equal");
    }
    else {
        println!("not equal")
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum test{
    a(usize),
}
```

Is there any way to do this in rust without implementing my own `PartialEq` trait?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`std::mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html).

Comment: Maybe compare primitive values? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028854/how-do-i-match-enum-values-with-an-integer#28029279