How to get an enum variant from its index?
I'm trying to write a high performance way to be able to convert between an enum variant (where none of the variants have data) and its index. Currently I am using a bunch of consts:
type: Foo = u8;
const FOO_A: Foo = 0;
const FOO_B: Foo = 1;
const FOO_C: Foo = 2;

Hopefully this gives you an idea of my goal. I really have quite a few of these kinds of structures, but I realize this is not very idiomatic. Ideally I would write something like this:
enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

However, I need to be able to convert Foo to and from its inner type. For example: Foo::A as u8 -> 0 and 0 as Foo -> Foo::A. The first one works just fine, but the second gives a justifiable (but in my case annoying) objection.
I could write a match statement, but I'm concerned about the speed. I'm doing this operation an enormous amount of times, so speed really is a concern. I could do a lookup table, but again it's still much slower than my very un-idiomatic const method.
I think this is a rare case where transmute is my best option. I know it's horribly unsafe, but I think something like this would work:
enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

fn from_index(i: u8) -> Option<Foo> {
    if i > 2 {
        None
    } else {
        unsafe { Some(std::mem::transmute(i)) }
    }
}

In my testing, this works fine, but I wanted to ask if there were any issues with this I may have missed. I see reper(C) used with this a lot, but it doesn't seem very obviously necessary in this particular case.
Even better, does anyone know of a way to do this without compromising on speed or using unsafe transmute?

I think a better dup to link to is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028854/how-do-i-match-enum-values-with-an-integer/28029667#28029667

Thanks to @Codebling. I will use transmute. Strum, num-derive, and enum_primitive all use matches or flat if elses to work their magic. Transmute seems safe if its value is checked. Thanks.

@Elliott No, match is safer, since you don't get UB if you are wrong (and LLVM generally optimizes them well to nop).

You can use #[repr(<int type>)] to make an enum backed by a specific integer type. This allows you to freely convert those enum values to that integer type (ex: Foo::A as u8).
#[repr(u8)]
enum Foo {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
}

However, there is no builtin way to convert an integer to an enum. Part of the reason for this is because the mapping may not be 1:1. Additionally, #[repr(...)] is for the enum's tag and does not include any fields of an enum variant. For example, this is a valid enum:
#[repr(u8, C)]
enum Foo {
    A = 0,
    B(u8) = 1,
}

// The tag might only be a single byte, but the enum needs another
// byte for the data on its largest variant. However, take this with
// a grain of salt because it still effected by all of the typical
// system-specific size considerations like alignment and packing.
assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<Foo>(), 2);

You generally get around this by implementing a function for the conversion.
struct InvalidConversion;

impl TryFrom<u8> for Foo {
    type Error = InvalidConversion;

    fn try_from(value: u8) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            0 => Ok(Foo::A),
            1 => Ok(Foo::B),
            2 => Ok(Foo::C),
            _ => Err(InvalidConversion),
        }
    }
}

However, it is generally easier to use a derive macro. A popular crate for doing this is num-derive.

Why might the mapping not be 1:1?

I guess that means every enum will have an int but not every int will have a matching enum value?

@Codebling, as you were guessing, the mapping would not be 1:1 if you did not have a variant for every value. Also, if variants have associated data, the entire thing gets a bit messy. To avoid these complications, the conversion is left up to the programmer instead of attempting to add language-level support that is subject to a number of preconditions.
